Can the eye lens not produce a virtual image when the object is between Focus and Optical Centre?
My teacher dismissed the question saying it is not possible for the eye to do so simply because we didn't know the focal length of the eye. That confused me. The focal length can vary, sure. When we look at a distant object, our eye's focal lenth increases. Let this focal lenth be called f1 so while we look at a distant object and bring another object infront of our eyes such that it lies within the focal length f1 (the same focal length as the former as the eyes are still focusing on a distant object). How do we see this object that is closer to us? I know that objects between F and O are always virtual and virtual images can't form at the retina. But though blurred, I still see an image of the closer object.

From object closer than say 2cm of your ey you don't see a "blurred" picture  but just nothing or the color of the object. just make a picture of the lens and just 1 point closer than f and you have large blot on the retina. (We know the range of the focal length, so your teacher is not right.)

I cant, can you really do it without knowing the text and guessing. @Shristeerupa. of cause the lens makes a virtual picture, a little man behind your lens in your head would see it, but not you i.e, the retina.

@trula when I formed a virtual image at school and placed a screen behind the lens, there was nothing, just the screen.No image formed. So shouldn't there be nothing on the screen of the eye, retina, here too?

We do indeed know the focal length of the lens in your eye.  It is the distance from the center of the lens to your retina.

Yes from a virtual image you have nothing on the screen, but still some light from the object in the right colors, that what I called blots
